# vee-validate not show errors on object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

While using

- vee-validate@4.5.6
- vue@3.2.26

i am trying to validate a nested object, however i have a problem with displaying an error

I made an example according to the documentation [docs](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/nested-objects-and-arrays)

but when i try add

```
:has-error="Boolean(formErrors.links?.twitter)"
```

i have error when try show popup message

```
Property 'twitter' does not exist on type 'string'
```

component script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// imports...libs
// const { value: name } = useField('name')
// const { value: twitter } = useField('links.twitter');
// const { value: github } = useField('links.github');

const { values: fieldValues, errors: formErrors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  initialValues: {
    name: '',
    links: {
      twitter: null,
      github: null,
    },
  },
  validationSchema: yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    links: yup.object({
      twitter: yup.string().required().nullable(),
      github: yup.string().required().nullable(),
    })
  })
})
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(values => {
  //some logic
});

const loading = ref(false)

</script>
```

component HTML

```
<template>
  <form @submit="onSubmit">
    <Field v-slot="{ field, errors }" name="name" type="text">
      <VField label="name">
        <VControl icon="feather:edit-2" :has-error="Boolean(formErrors.name)">
          <input
            v-bind="field"
            class="input is-primary-focus"
            type="text"
            placeholder="imagesLtr"
            autocomplete="name"
          />
          <p v-if="errors" class="help is-danger">{{ formErrors.name }}</p>
        </VControl>
      </VField>
    </Field>
    <Field v-slot="{ field, errors }" name="links.twitter" type="text">
      {{ field }}
      <VField label="links.twitter">
        <VControl icon="feather:edit-2" :has-error="Boolean(formErrors.links?.twitter)">
          <input
            v-bind="field"
            class="input is-primary-focus"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            autocomplete="twitter"
          />
          <p v-if="errors" class="help is-danger">{{ formErrors.links?.twitter }}</p>
        </VControl>
      </VField>
    </Field>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `formErrors['links.twitter']`?
It's how you access errors in nested objects when using vee-validate with [composition api](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-form)
Perhaps, can help

Comment: i try this but have this error

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"links.twitter"' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Record<"name" | "links", string | undefined>>'.
  Property 'links.twitter' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<"name" | "links", string | undefined>>'.ts(7053)